# Update array after event

Tags: javascript

I have a bar graph with the y-axis being data from an array. The array has two data points, one of which is a variable called checked. The variable is dependant on an event. 
When the page loads, the variable (checked) is still not created.
So the first column in the graph is set to zero. I would like the graph to get updated every time the variable checked changes.
Is this possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>To do list with reminder</title>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-R4pqcOYV8lt7snxMQO/HSbVCFRPMdrhAFMH+vr9giYI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>

<body>

 <div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h1>My Daily Tasks</h1>
  <p>Add a time and task then press enter. When finished task click on task bar</p>

  <p>To delete task click on <span id="x-text">x</span> in the corner of task bar</p>
  <input type="time" id="myInput1" value="06:00">
  <input name="text" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="My task...">

  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" id="myBtn"></span>
 </div>
 <ul id="columns">
  <!-- <li class="column" draggable="true">w</li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true">ff</li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true">uuu</li> -->
 </ul>
</body>
<script src="/app.js"></script>

<!-- adding a graph -->
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
 var checked = document.getElementsByClassName('column checked').length
 // var checked = 1;
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
   labels: ['Total Tasks', 'Completed Tasks'],
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Completed tasks',
    data: [checked, 9],
    backgroundColor: [
     'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
     'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
     'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
     'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
     'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
     'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
     'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
     'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
   }]
  },
  options: {
   scales: {
    yAxes: [{
     ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
     }
    }]
   }
  }
 });
</script>

</html>
```